Short story in which a retired man, living very simply, misses his old books and music and goes back in time to retrieve them
I'm trying to track down an obscure science fiction short story, probably from the 1950s/1960s (Robert Sheckley? Poul Anderson? A. E. van Vogt?). It's about a man who, after a busy and successful life, retires to live a simple existence in an idyllic little home (possibly a wooden shack by the sea somewhere), but comes to miss his old music and books. He somehow finds the means to travel back in time and retrieves them, so that he can then enjoy them when he comes to retire once again.
The reason for my curiosity is simply that I've done much the same thing, and I'd really like to re-read that story. Some years ago, I retired early and left England to be with close relatives in Australia, and to live out my life there. I bought a nice house and lived the good life but missed all the books and music CDs from my former life I had left behind. Fortunately I had agreed to give a lot of my stuff to a good friend with similar tastes, and he admitted that it was still all in a few big boxes in his shed, and promptly shipped them over to me.

How does the man travel back in time? Does he invent a time machine? Does he live in a future where you can buy or rent or hire a time machine? Does he use magic? A deal with the devil?
